# Program that scans your computer and explains what would be best hardware upgrades for it

Tags: open-source, hardware, memory-management, ssd

Is there a program that scans you computer, and shows what upgrades you would get the most out of? One that looks at all aspects from graphics, memory, as well as wifi cards, and network setups? preferably one that does not make or sale computer components!!!

Comment: Sorry, this typically depends on what you do with the PC. If you play games, you might benefit from a graphics card. If you do video editing, you might benefit from RAM. If you do calculations, you might benefit from CPU. A computer program can hardly detect this.

Comment: To address Thomas' concern, maybe the program could optionally provide improved advice after asking a few questions about the user's habits. Or even guess these habits by checking what programs are installed/etc.